# Render on option in ReactJs

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

I'm trying to render option of React element without select. Ho can do this.This code render both select and option elements.In my app i use an AngularJs directive to bind option so its duplicating the select the view.  How can I do this ?

```
return React.createElement('select',
    timeSheet.map(function (time, index) {
        var option = React.createElement('option', { value: time.value, key: index, label: time.lable, className: 'md-option' });
        return option;
      })
  )
```

AngularJs Directive.

```
angular.directive('timePicker', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      ngValue: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('ng-value', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        var MyComponent = React.createFactory(GRID);
        console.log(el[0])
        ReactDOM.render(
          MyComponent(),
          el[0]

        );
      })
    }
  }
})
```

React class can be find in this linked question.[GRID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45973206/react-not-rendering-child-elements)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your angular code? Also, this is probably a terrible idea, since you're managing state in 2 very different (angular directive and react component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only trying to add option elements inside of a select directive, which you are creating in angular, then just render the options into your select directive element...

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('mySelectDirective', function($compile){
    return {
      template: '<md-select ng-model="someModel"></md-select>',
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {

        var options = timeSheet.map(function (time, index) {
          return React.createElement('option', { value: time.value, key: index, label: time.lable, className: 'md-option' });
        });

        // append the React components to your select directive
        ReactDOM.render(options, element[0]);

        // apply Angular bindings to new elements
        $compile(element)(scope);
      }
    }
  })
```

Also, you still need to update the signature on React.createElement to match  `(component, props, ...children)`. (See [React Without JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-jsx.html) for more info)

Add `null` as the 2nd arg like this:

```
return React.createElement('select',
    null,
    timeSheet.map(function (time, index) {
        var option = React.createElement('option', { value: time.value, key: index, label: time.lable, className: 'md-option' });
        return option;
    })
)
```

Comment: The first solution throws error as invalid element, the second on not deal as what I expected.But its gave more understand on my problem.Thanks @Julian Soro

Comment: Well, seeing your GRID code, the first part would not work since the select is being made by React again...

Comment: I have the `select` in my Angular Meterial as `md-select`. I want to keep it as it and append the options to the md-select using react since the Angular take more time to render in this case.